# Set changed properties to spans

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have 20 spans on my page and I changed style of this spans but I don't want to apply to one of them in a div. I want set this span property to all spans except span in div with `id="no"` while this span keeps the default css. How I can do this?

This my html:

```
<span>Hi ...</span>
<span>Hi ...</span>
<span>Hi ...</span>
<span>Hi ...</span>
<span>Hi ...</span>

<div id="k">
   <span>Hi ...</span>
</div>

<div id="no">
     <span>Hi ...</span>
</div>
```

And this is my style:

```
span{
     display:block;
     font-size:20px;
}
```

**Edit**: I want also `id="k"` div's spans treated as same as `id="no"` div's spans.

Comment: What do you mean by `set this span to this div:id="k" and id="no"`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use combination of [`:not()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not) pseudo-class and direct descendant combinator `>`:

```css
:not(#k):not(#no) > span { /* Match all spans that are NOT children of */
  display:block;           /* elements having IDs #k and #no           */
  font-size:20px;
}
```

It's worth noting that `:not()` [is supported in IE9+](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sel3).

```css
:not(#k):not(#no) > span {
  display:block;
  font-size:20px;
}
```

```html
<span>Hi ...</span>
<span>Hi ...</span>
<span>Hi ...</span>
<span>Hi ...</span>
<span>Hi ...</span>

<div id="k">
   <span>Hi ...</span>
</div>

<div id="no">
     <span>Hi ...</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

What's the parent? If it is a div with a particular class you can do

```
.parent-class > span {
     display:block;
     font-size:20px;
}
```

the same goes if it is body, or an element or something with an id.

In css > is the direct child selector. A rule that has x > y will only select elements that match y which are direct children of x. So you can have #id-parent > p which will only select p elements that are direct children of the element with id="id-parent", or you could have p > .class-child which will only select elements with class='child-class' which are direct children of p elements.

An example of those:

```
<div id="id-parent">
  <p> <!-- This will be matched by #id-parent > p -->
    Some text
    <div>
      <span class="class-child"> <!-- This won't be matched by p > .class-child -->
          A span
       </span>
    </div>
  </p>
  <div id="id-child">
    <p> <!-- This will be won't be matched by #id-parent > p -->
       Some more text
       <span class="class-child"> <!-- This will be matched by p > .class-child -->
          A span
       </span>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not classes?

```
<span class="some-class">Hi ...</span>
...
<span class="some-class">Hi ...</span>

<div id="k">
  <span class="some-class">Hi ...</span>
</div>

<div id="no">
  <span>Hi ...</span>
</div>
```

```
.some-class {
   ...
}
```